# How do I group by hour and count number of entries in each bin using R

Tags: r, count, grouping

Sample of Data imported form csv file:

1 24/05/2014 00:15
2 24/05/2014 00:17
3 24/05/2014 00:17
4 24/05/2014 00:17
5 24/05/2014 01:40
6 24/05/2014 01:48

I would like to group by hour and then have a group count in R, eg.

date                                                          count
24/05/2014 00:00        4
24/05/2014 01:00        2

Would really appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
db <- data.frame(time =  Sys.time() + seq(1, 10000, by = 100),
                 counter = 1)

res <- aggregate(db$counter,
                 by=list(format(db$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H")),
                 sum)

names(res) <- c("date","count")
res
```

HTH